# Folding variadic template checking for existence of a member function

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, sfinae

I am using SFINAE idiom to check if a type has method with certain signature (`function_name()`). The solution I have implemented works for a single type but I want to make it work with multiple types (through variadic templates).

```
template <typename... Other>
class has_foo {
   public:
    static constexpr bool value = has_foo<Other...>::value;
};

template <typename U, typename ...Other> // Error here
class has_foo {
   public:
    static constexpr bool value = has_foo<U>::value && has_foo<Other...>::value;
};

template <typename U>
class has_foo {
   private:
    template <typename T, T>
    struct helper;
    template <typename T>
    static std::uint8_t check(helper<int (*)(size_t), &T::function_name>*);
    template <typename T>
    static std::uint16_t check(...);

   public:
    static constexpr bool value = sizeof(check<U>(0)) == sizeof(std::uint8_t);
};

template <>
class has_foo<void> {
   public:
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};
```

I get the following error: `too many template parameters in template redeclaration`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The first `has_foo` is a primary template, the others should be partial specializations (like `has_foo<U, Other...>` etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
template <typename U, typename ...Other>
class has_foo {
public:
    static constexpr bool value = has_foo<U>::value && has_foo<Other...>::value;
};

// partial template specialization
template <typename... Other>
class has_foo<void, Other...>{
public:
    static constexpr bool value = has_foo<void,Other...>::value;
};

// partial template specialization
template <typename U>
class has_foo<U,void> {
private:
    template <typename T, T>
    struct helper;
    template <typename T>
    static std::uint8_t check(helper<int (*)(size_t), &T::function_name>*);
    template <typename T>
    static std::uint16_t check(...);

public:
    static constexpr bool value = sizeof(check<U>(0)) == sizeof(std::uint8_t);
};

// partial template specialization
template <>
class has_foo<void> {
public:
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if I can't test it for it is not a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), maybe the code below will work fine for you.

```
template<typename... Args>
class has_foo { };

template <typename U, typename ...Other>
class has_foo<U, Other...>: public has_foo<Other...> {
    template <typename t, t>
    struct helper;

    template <typename t>
    static std::uint8_t check(helper<int (*)(size_t), &t::function_name>*);

    template <typename t>
    static std::uint16_t check(...);

public:
    static constexpr bool value = (sizeof(check<U>(0)) == sizeof(std::uint8_t)) && has_foo<Other...>::value;
};

template <>
class has_foo<> {
public:
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

template <>
class has_foo<void> {
public:
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};
```

Here a reduced revision that also compiles:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename... Args>
class has_foo { };

template <typename U, typename ...Other>
class has_foo<U, Other...>: public has_foo<Other...> {
public:
    static constexpr bool value = true && has_foo<Other...>::value;
};

template <>
class has_foo<> {
public:
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

template <>
class has_foo<void> {
public:
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << has_foo<int, double, char>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << has_foo<int, double, void>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << has_foo<>::value << std::endl;
}
```

The basic idea is to define a variadic structure that is then specialized for all those required cases that let it works, other than the `void` one that looks to be of interest for you.

Currently, it returns `true` for the last case in the example and I'm not sure how to handle this case, for you didn't give any suggestion. Anyway, starting from the example above, you can easily modify it according with your requirements.